# jPanel button triggering another class in java

Tags: java, button, jpanel

So, I have a Class called `Math`, that runs a small piece of code, and another class called GUI that holds a button and a text box. I need to make it so pressing the button runs the Math class.

In the Math Class:

```
public class Math {

 public static int com;

 public static void main (String[] args) {
     com = GUI.num1 * GUI.num2;
     GUI.TextBox3.setText(com);
    }
}
```

In the GUI class (It's jPanel, by the way):

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static int num1;
public static int num2;

public GUI() {
    initComponents();
}
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
      num1 = Integer.parseInt(TextBox1.getText());
      num1 = Integer.parseInt(TexBox2.getText());
      Math.main (Sring[] );//This is the part the doesn't work

}
```

If you could help, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass {

     public static int com;
     public static void Method()
       {
       com = GUI.num1 * GUI.num2;
       GUI.TextBox3.setText(""+com);
       }

    }
```

And

```
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
          num1 = Integer.parseInt(TextBox1.getText());
          num2 = Integer.parseInt(TexBox2.getText());
          MyClass.Method();
    }
```

This will be more Convenient.

Here

```
 GUI.TextBox3.setText(com);
```

`TextBox3` also needs to be static.

*NOTE: You even don't need the class for calculation directly calculate*

```
TextBox3.setText(""+(num1*num2));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the GUI class is giving an error (can't find symbol method Method() in class Math), and I have a different class because I am planning on expanding the Math class to be more complex later.

Comment: _I have a different class_ than use `className.Method()` because Method is `static` (className is your class's name which is replaced with Math)

Comment: Never mind, the error way me misspelling  something, so there is no errors, and it works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: `"TextBox3 also needs to be static"` --  Are you sure you should be advising him to do this? Is this encouraging good OOP programming practice?

Comment: Not advising but as he used `GUI.TextBox3` in another method so..Well as answerer it's obviously not possible to cover all possible aspect but as OP required I put it in quote.

Comment: `num1 = Integer.parseInt(TextBox1.getText());`

`num1 = Integer.parseInt(TexBox2.getText());`

See the redundancy people?

Comment: Not redundancy it's typo see method where OP looking for calculation.as well as OP had declared two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You better don't call your class `Math` since java already have a class called like this, it might create some conflict.

What is your error?

Looking at your code, a don't understand how your Math class can access your GUI, is this all the code?

You better replace your Math.main(...) with :

```
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(TextBox1.getText());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(TexBox2.getText());
    TextBox3.setText(String.valueOf(num1 * num2));
}
```

**Edit, fixed an error**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more appropriate answer

```
public class MyMath {

 public static int com;

 public int squareIt(int a, int b) {
     com = a * b;
     return com; // return a*b;
    }
}
```

This would make your life a whole lot easier and you could modify your front-end(GUI) like so:

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static int num1;
public static int num2;

public GUI() {
    initComponents();
}
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
      num1 = Integer.parseInt(TextBox1.getText());
      num2 = Integer.parseInt(TexBox2.getText());
      TextBox3.setText(""+new MyMath().squareIt(num1,num2));

}  
}
```